# Multiply a BigDecimal with an Integer

Tags: scala, bigdecimal

I want to multiply a financial amount with a quantity. I know Scala uses Java's BigDecimal under the hood but the syntax doesn't seem to be the same.

```scala
val price = BigDecimal("0.01") // £0.01
val qty   = 10
```

I tried to do this

```scala
BigDecimal(price).*(BigDecimal(qty))
```

But it's a compile error. If I look at the Java SO posts you can pass integer into BigDecimal and then multiply it like this

```
BigDecimal(price).multiply(BigDecimal(qty))
```

So how do you do this in Scala? And are there any dangers in losing precision by multiplying a decimal and integer like this? I will need sum a lot of these together as well

Comment: Simply `price * qty`?

Comment: @XavierGuihot so there is no loss in precision at all, in every case, with multiplying a BigDecimal with an integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually multiply a `BigDecimal` with an `Int` using `BigDecimal`'s [multiplication operator](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/math/BigDecimal.html#*(that:scala.math.BigDecimal):scala.math.BigDecimal):

> def *(that: BigDecimal): BigDecimal

since the `Int` you will provide as its parameter will be [implicitly converted to a `BigDecimal`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/math/BigDecimal$.html#int2bigDecimal(i:Int):scala.math.BigDecimal) based on:

> implicit def int2bigDecimal(i: Int): BigDecimal

---

You can thus safely multiply your `BigDecimal` with an `Int` as if it was a `BigDecimal` and receive a `BigDecimal` with no loss in precision:

```
val price = BigDecimal("0.01")
// scala.math.BigDecimal = 0.01
val qty   = 10
// Int = 10
price * qty // same as BigDecimal("0.01").*(10)
// scala.math.BigDecimal = 0.10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
val a = 10
val b = BigDecimal(0.1000000000001)
a * b

res0: scala.math.BigDecimal = 1.0000000000010
```

As you can see you don´t lose precision

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually this:

```
BigDecimal(price)
```

`price` is already a `BigDecimal` so the compiler does't know what to do! If you fix this, the first version works. The second version fails because there is no `multiply` method on `BigDecimal`.

However, as others have pointed out, the simple solution is just

```
price*qty
```